# Looking for code examples of how to price a worst of (aka multi-asset or minimum of two assets) call/put option

Tags: options, derivatives

I can find a bunch of phd level formulas for pricing worst of options, but haven't come across anything that translates the math formulas into a programming language.

Are there any known references to textbooks with actual code examples to check out?

Been searching for code that outputs fair value and respective greeks.

Some references of what a worst of option is
https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/0/30211/files/2016/05/Options-on-the-Minimum-or-Maximum-q6ixkg.pdf

https://www2.superderivatives.com/CM/CMHelp/Content/FM/Worst_of_Option.htm

Comment: I believe [Esper Haug's book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0071389970) has some worst to put code examples, although they may be too simplistic.

Comment: good call.  I was searching that book before but was looking for the wrong keywords.  thanks for the recommendation.  I see some formulaic examples for OPTIONS ON THE MAXIMUM OR THE MINIMUM OF TWO RISKY ASSETS

Comment: I think quantlib should allow you to do it: [basketoption.cpp](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/master/test-suite/basketoption.cpp). If you have access to Bloomberg you could compare the price with DLIB.